# Getting true width of a nested DIV using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, width

In my sample page: http://j25.wasen.net/modules/mod_simplefilelisterv2.0/index.html

I have added a DIV as a wrapper at 200px wide.

I use jQuery to try and detect the width of DIV's inside this DIV but they all come out as 200px wide also even though they are wider (or narrower).

I have tried several different techniques found here at the site but all has failed this far... How can I get the TRUE width of the DIV's in the wrapper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `display: inline-block` as a style for the divs. At the moment `display: block` will make the divs as big as their parent while the tags inside are have a display value of `inline`.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify the widths of the divs inside the element. They are block elements, and will automatically inherit the width of the parent.

If you want them to have true widths based on their text, you can try an inline-element like span, or explicitly declare them as inline or inline-block. For items bigger than the parent, you need to specify white-space:nowrap; though.

You can see what I mean by using Developer Tools on Chrome, or Firebug on Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example, do the following:

CSS:

```
.item{ display: inline-block; }
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/StPGT/2/